# How to write 1000 records per file or wait to have more record to write then break file?

Tags: java, multithreading, filewriter

I have generating data of users with auto-increment ID, then write it to file following these rules:

- Name the file in following structure `(FileCounter)_(StartID)_(EndID)`
- Maximum 1000 records per file
- If don't have enough 1000 records to write, wait maximum 10s, if any added, write it all to file otherwise, write the remain list to file (not enough 1000),  if nothing to write after wait, create empty file with naming `(FileCounter)_0_0`

My approach is using 2 thread, 1 thread to generate data then push it to the queue, 1 thread to take from the queue add to a list then write the list to the file.

```
//Generate function
public void generatedata() {
int capacity = 1678;
synchronized(users) {
for(int index = 0; index <capacity; index++) {          
users.add(generateUser());
// notify to read thread
users.notifyAll();
}
} 
//Write function
public void writeToFile(ArrayList<User> u) {
String fileName  ="";
if(!u.isEmpty()) {
String filename = "" + (++FileCounter) + "_"+ u.get(0).getId() + "_" + 
u.get(u.size() - 1).getId() + ".txt";
try {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename, true);
for (User x : u) {
System.out.println(x.toString());
    writer.write(x.getId() + " | " + x.getFormatedDate() + " | " + 
x.getSex()  + " | " + x.getPhoneNum().getPhoneNumber() + " | " + 
x.getPhoneNum().getProvider() + "\r\n");
}
writer.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
}
else {
    try {
        fileName = ""+(++FileCounter) +"_0_0.txt";
        File f = new File(fileName);
        f.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UsersManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
null, ex);
    }
}
}
//Read function
    public ArrayList<User> ReadFromQueue(ArrayList<User> u) {
    while(true) {
    try {

    int size = users.size();
    if(users.isEmpty() && u.size() < 1000) {
        users.wait(10000);

        if(isChanged(size)) {
            System.out.println("Size changed here");
            u.add(users.take());
        }
        else return u;
    }
    if(u.size() == 1000)  {
        System.out.println("Check the size is 1000");
        return u;
    }
     u.add(users.take());
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(UsersManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
    null, ex);
    }
    }
```

It work fine when I run 1 thread to generate data, 1 thread to read then write data to file but when I use 2++ thread for each generate thread of write thread, There are 1 problems :

1. The list written in the file still has 1000 records as expected but not sequential at all, it only ascending order.

My output is like:

```
1_2_1999.txt
2_1_2000.txt
3_2001_3000.txt
```

My expected output is like:

```
1_1_1000.txt
2_1001_2000.txt
....
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `function generatedata() {` - This doesn't look like Java to me.

Comment: @JacobG. Sr, I edited this

Comment: It feels like you need to put `synchronized` on the `writeToFile` method. Can you try that?

Comment: I tried it but no different! The file generated still not sequential

Answer (score 0):

using the thread approach is best for when you do not want to control the amount per file. but since you have a constraint of 1000 records, it's probably easier to use a counter;

```
 public class DataReaderWriter(){

//keeps track of where you left off at, which row in source data.        
static int currentRowInSourceData = 0;

        public static void main(String[] args){

        List<ContactRecord> contacts = getMoreData();
        writeRecords(contacts);
    }



    writeRecords(List<ContactRecord> contacts){

    int maxRecords = currentRowInSourceData+1000;
    for(int i = currentRowInSourceData;i<maxRecords;i++){
        ContactRecord c = contacts.get(i);
        writeToFile(c);
        currentRowInSourceData++;

    }

    }
```

Comment: My task must be implemented in multithreading, It's not always 1000 records per file, it can be less if after wait write cant receive enough records, these record still be written!. I change my code from sleep the read thread to let the users(queue) to wait up to 10s, for generate thread to generate data, after generate, users(queue) will notify the read thread. It solves the constraint of 1000 records per file. But messy when I increase like 2 generate -2 writer thread

Answer (score 0):

I had a project where I needed to create 90 second previews from larger MP4 files. What I did was to have multiple threads start up with access to a shared Queue of file names. Each thread consumes work from the Queue by using queue.poll().

Here is the Constructor:

```
public Worker(Queue<String> queue, String conferenceYear, CountDownLatch startSignal, CountDownLatch doneSignal) {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.startSignal = startSignal;
        this.doneSignal = doneSignal;
    }
```

Then, as I said above, I keep polling for data:

```
public void run() {
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {

                String fileName = queue.poll() + ".mp4";

                File f = new File("/home/ubuntu/preview_" + fileName);
                if (fileName != null && !f.exists()) {
                    System.out.println("Processing File " + fileName + "....");
```

I started these threads in another class called WorkLoad:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        BlockingQueue<String> filesToDownload = new LinkedBlockingDeque<String>(1024);
        BlockingQueue<String> filesToPreview = new LinkedBlockingDeque<String>(1024);
        BlockingQueue<String> filesToUpload = new LinkedBlockingDeque<String>(1024);

for (int x = 0; x < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; x++) {
                workers[x] = new Thread(new Worker(filesToPreview, currentYear, startSignal, doneSignal));
                workers[x].start();
            }
```

In your specific case, you could provide each thread its own file name, or a handle on a file. If you want the file names and entries in a chronological sequence, then just start 2 threads, 1 for acquiring data and placing on a queue, with a barrier/limit of 1000 records, and the other thread as a consumer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! It only works sequential when I have 2 thread (I have done it), but I need to increase the number of thread both generate and write data Thread but still keep writing in sequential order. My teacher said, I need to change my approach  to divide the task into as small as possible task to minimize amount of lock activity to keep the sequential order

Answer (score 0):

the original code creates multiple threads. I am able to create 90 second snippets from over 1000 MP4 videos in about 30 minutes.

Here I am creating a thread per processor, I usually end up with at least 4 threads on my AWS EC2 instance:

```
/**
         * Here we can find out how many cores we have.
         * Then make the number of threads NUMBER_OF_THREADS = the number of cores.
         */
        NUMBER_OF_THREADS = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        System.out.println("Thread Count: "+NUMBER_OF_THREADS);

for (int x = 0; x < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; x++) {
            workers[x] = new Thread(new MyClass(param1, param2));
            workers[x].start();
        }
```

Comment: but I dont understand why when you create more thread (to generate data and to write to the file) like 2 generate -2 write it still can be sequential 1,2,3,4,5... like this? I dont think your implementation here can be chronological.

Comment: It can. each thread can have an integer field calledax records. Just prevent any single thread from taking more 1000 records from the queue/data source.